# Gradle build succeeds with sdk.dir in local.properties, but not with ANDROID_SDK_ROOT defined

Tags: android, linux, gradle, environment-variables

My gradle build is failing with the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/ubuntu/hello_world_android/local.properties'.

This issue is in fact resolved by adding a local.properties with "sdk.dir = /opt/android-sdk-linux" to the project. However since this is intended to be used as a build machine I'd like to avoid needing to create that file for each project and instead use an environment variable. I've tried setting both ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME to /opt/android-sdk-linux, however I keep getting the same error so long as it is not set in local.properties.

Is there any way around needing this local.properties file?

Comment: is `ANDROID_HOME` added to all users? It may be added only to the current user, or you might need to restart the machine or Studio.

Comment: I've tried restarting the machine. ANDROID_HOME is set for the user doing the build.

Comment: Try printing the enviroment variables from bash, I think it's `env` or `printenv`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it for some time I tried moving the environment variables from .bashrc to /etc/environment and restarted. Somehow that worked, not sure why.